# Django Model ForeignKey Reciprocation

Tags: python, django, model

I'm wondering what the best way to reciprocate the existence of the ForeignKey would be for a model. I.e. I want to be able to see the associated ForeignKey in the Model in the admin page, not just the initial instance of the model.

#### Email Models.py

```
class ScheduledEmail(models.Model):
    primary_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    recipient_name = models.TextField()
    subject = models.TextField()
    message = models.TextField()
    datetime_sent = models.TextField(max_length=20, default='Not Yet Sent')
    datetime_created = models.TextField(max_length=20)
    recipient_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Email Not Found')
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  related_name='scheduled_emails_sent')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.primary_key},{self.recipient_name}, {self.message}, {self.datetime_sent},' \
               f'{self.datetime_created}, {self.recipient_email}, {self.sent}, {self.recipient}'
```

#### Client Models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    primary_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unique_num = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=30, default='Name Not Found')
    number = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, {self.number}, {self.email}, {self.unique_num}, {self.primary_key}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes the list_display section and the recipient column (inside your admin panel) to show both what you want in the ScheduledEmail class and your recipient value at the same time. Since we can not show ManytoMany and foreign key values, we have to convert them to str. By the way, I used this feature in my project; let me Show output:

[image]

in this, I have shown my game in 'title' column and its platform(that is a ManytoMany field) in 'platform' column(Foreign key and ManytoMany are the same in this regard).

> this is my admin panel and I said show each games and their platform

```
class GameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'image_tag', 'platform_to_str')
    search_fields = ('title', 'slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug":("title",)}

    def platform_to_str(self, obj):
        return ", ".join([platform.title for platform in 
    obj.platform.all()])
    platform_to_str.short_description = "platform"

admin.site.register(Game, GameAdmin)
```

> And this is my model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)
```

> And for example in your admin.py we should say:

```
class ScheduledEmailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('all thing that you want to show in admin panel', 'recipient_to_str')
    search_fields = ('title', 'description')

    def recipient_to_str(self, obj):
        return ", ".join([client.recipient for recipient in obj.recipient.all()])
    recipient_to_str.short_description = "recipient"
```

Because I do not know what your recipient in the Client class is equal to, so I said 'client.recipient'.

I hope it was clear if not ask again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I added the model.py for both apps in reference. Didn't add them before as I thought it would just convolute a simple question.

Comment: Would you be able to update the answer? I cannot figure out how to do it for my model ahaha.

Comment: @BakedPotato I have edited it, Take a look at it

Comment: I appreciate that.

Comment: I've tried to figure out how to do exactly this but through separate models. As mine are separated (as specified) separate. I.e. Clients -> models.py (contains Client model) and Email -> models.py (contains ScheduledEmail model)

Comment: I've never worked with two models but I think you have to relate these two models with import or something else and then do this that I have done